# merge changes to git repo as if they had happened in the past

Tags: git

I'm pretty new to git, so forgive me if this is obvious (or impossible)!

I am using it for CMS websites. I often run into the situation where I have made modifications to a 3rd-party component that is then updated.

How can I add the changes from the updated component as if they had happened before my changes? or is this 'rewriting history'?

Do I create a branch from an old commit where the component was introduced, add the updated code and then merge into master? submodules? or am I barking up the wrong tree and this situation is better handled another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(originally this answer assumed the 3rd party component came from a public git repo, @jacob-dorman has clarified that he obtains updates by copying the component's code from snapshots of a larger project)*

You need to maintain a repository with **two** branches:

- `master` : every time you get a new snapshot of the component, commit it to this branch
- `tweaks` : a branch based off the `master` branch, which contains the commits that constitute your custom tweaks

Every time you update the 'master' branch with new snapshots of the component, rebase the `tweaks` branch on top of the `master` branch:

```
$ git rebase master tweaks
```

This will leave your tweaks as effectively being *the last thing that happened*.

So, starting from the very beginning, this is what it would look like on the command line...

## Grab the first snapshot & store it on the 'master' branch

```
mkdir my-fork-of-shinything
cd my-fork-of-shinything
git init
cp -R /tmp/shinything-snapshot-1 .  # copy the snapshot of code into your repo
git add -A    // stages ALL directory contents for commit
git commit -m "V1 snapshot of the shinything component"
```

That sets up your 'master' branch.

## Add your tweaks on a new 'tweaks' branch

```
git checkout -b tweaks   // creates your new branch
... make your tweaks, commit them
```

Later, when some interesting updates have been made to original component...

## Grab a new component snapshot, update 'master' & 'tweaks' branches

```
git checkout master
rm -Rf * // delete the contents of the old snapshot
cp -R /tmp/shinything-snapshot-2 . // get the brand new snapshot in place
git add -A
git commit -m "V2 snapshot of shinything, brings fix for #234"
```

Your master branch now has an updated history of the component, with a commit for each snapshot update. Finally *rebase* the 'tweaks' branch on to the master branch - each of the commits on your 'tweaks' branch will be replayed, one after the other, on top of the new tip of the master branch:

```
git rebase master tweaks // re-bases the commits from your tweaks branch
```

## More tweaks?

If you ever need to add more tweaks, just check the branch out and add them:

```
git checkout tweaks
... make your tweaks, commit them
```

Comment: Will this work if I already have my tweaks to shinything in master?

ie. Go back to when shinything was added to the repository and create a branch to hold updates to shinything?

Comment: I'm still not clear on how to do this in reverse. shinything is a component that is not available under version control. It is part of a larger project and I will periodically download a new version and need the new version's changes to be added before my tweaks to it.

Answer (score 0):

A easy command for you, `git pull --rebase`

Br,
Tim

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more?